# using define to store the result of a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Good evening, i want to ask about the feasibility of something so i have a select statement inside this select a lot of similare subqueries
i want to use a sub-query only once and store it's result I have tried something like that but I don't know what to do
any help would be appreciated

```
define A = Select somthing from TableA
Select case
          when A <0
          then 1
          else 2
          End as selectedcolumn   from TableB
```

But i think that define is used only with static values

Comment: Oracle <> MySQL. Please specify which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: i'm using oracle

Comment: I think Common Table Expressions is what you need but you're question is not clear. Check this link : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html

Comment: Could you provide some sample data or more detail about your question?

Comment: I have a Subquery used many times inside may principal query 
`SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM TableA A
        WHERE A.ColumnA = B.ColumnB
        AND A.ColumnA2 = 0` this is my subquery

Comment: and i want to do something like `WITH A AS SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM TableA A
        WHERE A.ColumnA = B.ColumnB
        AND A.ColumnA2 = 0
        Select A As test from TableA ta  inner join TableB tb on ta.columnA=tb.columnB`

Comment: You're pretty close, you just need to join your CTE and add a column alias, e.g. `WITH A AS SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM TableA A WHERE A.ColumnA = B.ColumnB AND A.ColumnA2 = 0 Select A.c As test from TableA ta inner join TableB tb on ta.columnA=tb.columnB cross join A`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a CTE, e.g.

```
WITH A AS 
  SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM TableA A 
  WHERE A.ColumnA = B.ColumnB 
    AND A.ColumnA2 = 0 
Select A.c As test 
  from TableA ta 
inner join TableB tb 
  on ta.columnA=tb.columnB 
cross join A
```

This will make `A.c` available in your query. You can also then do `(select c from A)` anywhere in your query to get the value.

Alternately, if you're running a script in SQL*Plus, you can define a column variable using `new_value`:

```
COLUMN my_count NEW_VALUE my_constant
SELECT COUNT(*) my_count FROM TableA A 
  WHERE A.ColumnA = B.ColumnB 
    AND A.ColumnA2 = 0;
```

Then you can refer to it later on in your script using the substitution string `&&my_constant`:

```
Select case
      when &&my_constant <0
      then 1
      else 2
      End as selectedcolumn from TableB
```